# Strange CSS Class Name, someone explain to me what is going on?

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to make a bit of a copy of [this website](http://pixelarity.com/items/demos/overflow/green/) but i'm having issues with the gallery part, my images simply won't behave the same as the website im attempt to copy. Obviously change around once complete.

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/90uc1r6o/) of my code if that helps.

Here is my CSS for the section:

```
/* Gallery Start */
.box.style2 header {
    display:inline-block;
    background:#FFF;
    padding:2em 3em;
    margin:0px; 
}
.box.style2 .inner {
    position:relative;
    padding:40px 0 0px 0;
}
.box.style2 {
    text-align:center;
}
.box.style2 .inner:after {
    content: '';
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:50%;
    height:100%;
    border-left:solid 1px #FFF;
}
.box.style2 .inner .row {
    position:relative;  
}
.row {
    border-bottom:solid 1px transparent;
    box-sizing:border-box;  
}
.row:after, .row:before {
    content: '';
    display:block;
    clear:both;
    height:0;
}
.row > * {
    float:left;
}
.box.style2 .inner .image {
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    padding:20px;
}
.image.fit {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
}
.gallery-image {
    width:25%;
    margin-left:0px;    
}
/* Gallery END */
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<!-- Start of gallery -->
<article class="container box style2">
    <header>
        <h2>Recent Work</h2>
        <p>Below are images of our recent completed work</p>
    </header>
    <div class="inner gallery">
        <!-- Gallery Images -->
        <div class="row">
            <!-- Image -->
            <div class="gallery-image">
                <a href class="image fit" style="outline: 0px;">
                  <img src="images/01.jpg" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <!-- Image END -->

            <!-- Image -->
            <div class="gallery-image">
                <a href class="image fit" style="outline: 0px;">
                  <img src="images/01.jpg" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <!-- Image END -->

            <!-- Image -->
            <div class="gallery-image">
                <a href class="image fit" style="outline: 0px;">
                  <img src="images/01.jpg" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <!-- Image END -->

            <!-- Image -->
            <div class="gallery-image">
                <a href class="image fit" style="outline: 0px;">
                  <img src="images/01.jpg" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <!-- Image END -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Gallery Images END -->
</article>
<!-- End of gallery -->
```

Here is a screenshot of what my images look like, as you can see, they are not behaving at all.

I think this is because I don't have these styles, but I can't for the life of me figure out what they mean, all that I can understand from Google is that they are classes made from numbers:

```
.row.\30 \25 > * {
    padding: 0px 0 0 0px;
}
/* Inherited from: @media screen and (max-width: 1680px}*/
.row > * {
    padding: 40px 0 0 40px;
}
.\33 u, .\33 u\24 {
    width: 25%;
    clear: none;
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

edit: so after readying wero's answer, am I understanding this properly?

`.row.\30 \25 > *` would basically target a class with the name `0` within the `row` class, and then the element within `30` with class `25` and then style the next element within that?

Comment: looks like an encoding issue. the "strange" numbers you see are unicode text. It seems that the files you tried to copy are encoded with utf-8. what method did you use to copy the files from the website?

Comment: I'm just using Chrome's Inspect Element

Comment: Let me get this straight. You're trying to lift a design that the website sells, and you're asking for help deciphering it?

Comment: I thought that it's Loyalty Free? I read the license, or is this sold!? Crap!

Comment: are you copying the styles from the top right side of chrome's inspect element?

Comment: Well it looks like a subscription based service to me, but I couldn't be arsed to go reading through their license.

Comment: @anurupr - Yeah, once it works I want to change them around, it's just getting the layout working.

Comment: understood. but are you saving those changes in a file? if so check the encoding of the file before you save those changes. if you can tell us what editor you are using , then we can look for a more specific solution

Comment: @anurupr - no i'm simply typing them into my styles, as they i can understand more what the style is doing. I'm using Dreamwaver

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\nn<space>` syntax is a character escape sequence for the Unicode character U+00nn.

This [article](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes) describes the topic very nicely.

Using the escape sequences they build [valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/which-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors/6732899#6732899) CSS class identifiers.

Why do they do this? Can only speculate: For brevity, to generate unique names?

---

EDIT to answer the extended question:

`.row.\30 \25 > *` is a selector for all elements (`*`) whose parent element (`>`) has the CSS class `row` and the CSS class consisting of the two characters U+0030 and U+0025.

Comment: Thanks, I will look at this

Comment: Ah thanks, seems like JavaScript will be in affect here as U+0030 U+0025 is 0%